# Enabling a member function only if template parameter has member function

Tags: c++, templates

I have seen similiar questions, that already contain solutions, for example this one: 
[Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

However I am wondering why my solution is working on VC2015 but not on GCC5.1.
GCC gives me the following error:

> error: ‘get_result’ is not a member of ‘std::remove_reference_t>> > {aka main()::}’
>           templatedecltype(&std::remove_reference_t::get_result)(TSink)>

my code:

```
template <typename TSink>
struct Consume{
    ...
    TSink& _sink;
    Consumer(TSink& sink) : _sink(sink){};
    ...
    template<typename = decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<TSink>::get_result)(TSink)>
    auto
    get_result()
    {
        return _sink.get_result();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<TSink>::get_result)(TSink)` supposed to do?

Comment: Did you enable c++14? `-std=c++14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFINAE should only work on template parameters in the immediate context of a template.

You can bring `TSink` into this immediate context by simply adding another template parameter with a default argument:

```
template<typename Sink = TSink,
         typename = decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<Sink>::get_result)(Sink)>
auto
get_result()
{
    return _sink.get_result();
}
```